# How can I get natural language data from Instagram? Should I use the official API or is it better to use data scraping methods?

Tags: python, nlp, instagram, data-mining, social-media

I am working on a data analytics project to research the rise of [toxic masculinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxic_masculinity) on [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram) amongst [Persian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language) users. I had a straightforward method to get data from Twitter and was able to get data using both the *official* API and the unofficial data-scraping Python library called Snscrape.

The method for Twitter included getting certain amounts of data within a specific timeframe like this:

```
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('Keyword since:2021-07-05 until:2022-07-06').get_items()):
    if i>150:
        break
    attributes_container.append([tweet.date, tweet.likeCount, tweet.sourceLabel, tweet.content])
```

But for Instagram, the API is too complicated to me, and I don’t even know if I can get data like this. To be clear, I need to get natural language data on a certain keyword, for example, get 1000 comments that include #Alpha_Male in them. Or get 100 posts that have that hashtag. Then I can analyze the data using LDA and sentiment analysis methods.

Do you know if this kind of research is possible at all? If yes, can you please tell me the tools I need to get the data? I do have an API from Facebook developers and I have active apps for Instagram there. But I don't have any idea how to use them in my research. Even if you can help me by introducing a good Python library, I would deeply appreciate it.

In an attempt to gather natural language data from Instagram for my research project on the rise of toxic masculinity within the Persian language user community, I initially explored the possibility of using the Instagram API. Given my successful experience with Twitter data collection using the Official API and Snscrape, I was optimistic about finding a similar approach for Instagram.

My first step involved reviewing the Instagram Graph API documentation and understanding the available endpoints and parameters. With an active API key from Facebook developers and registered Instagram applications, but I find it too complicated and I am not sure that getting such data is available using this method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.

Comment: What is [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDA)? [Linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Latent Dirichlet allocation